# How to tell if an NFT jpg is stored on a legitimate IPFS domain?

Tags: ipfs, nft, server-side

usually URLs of NFTs point to well-known IPFS servers like `ipfs.io` and some gateway that bridges from the web to IPFS,

but what about cases where an NFT is pointed towards something like

`https://f8n-ipfs-production.imgix.net/[NFT_contract_name_here]`.

This looks just like any other web URL, i have no idea what company "imgix" is, and the inclusion of `ipfs` in the sub-domain could be nothing but a trick.

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of the "[Don't Trust. Verify.](https://store.blockstream.com/product/dont-trust-verify-tshirt/)™" maxim, you can verify the IPFS hash yourself through a known, trustworthy IPFS gateway.

For example, the following URL routes through an IPFS node hosted by Cloudflare, which may or may not be trustworthy (it is, but let's pretend it might not be):

https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco

The last part of the path is the IPFS hash: `QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco`

This can be fed through a public, trusted IPFS gateway to check the potentially questionable gateway is resolving honestly:

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco